# I made soap request with the help of ksoap2 but no response

Tags: android

```
Am new to android I made soap request with the help of Ksoap2,I manage to request and get responce without any parameters ,But when I pass the parameters it doesnt responce me.
Android code:
    private static final String METHOD_NAME ="HelloWorld";
     private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
     private static final String NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org";
     private static final String URL ="http://10.0.2.2:64580/Service1.asmx";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
       // SoapObject parameters = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

      request.addProperty("s1","A");
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request   
       AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
      httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent 
                                     //message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
        try {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        System.out.println("hhishihihii");  
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyOut;
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
         System.out.println("result"+response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //send request
         //SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        //SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    //SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyOut;

                  }
}
  WEBSERVICE CODE:
namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(String s1)
        {
            return s1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my part i used soap primitive, because of my service method return primitive type.

In your one,  `request.addProperty("s1","A");` Your method parameter name is "S1"

carefully check your parameter name & try this code;

```
    // ksoap2 calling wcf
public SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION,String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapPrimitive responses = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); // set up
    request.addProperty("strExec", strExecutive);
    request.addProperty("strBusinessUnit", strBusinessUnit);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        responses = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        }catch(SocketException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return responses;
}
```